# Performance test and RPS

Tags: performance, testing

I got a website to test its performance. The website is backed by a SQL Server database.

I am not quite sure about how the RPS (Request Per Second) is related to the performance test. And how should I set my RPS. Someone told me that if the RPS is too high, the performance test is meaningless. Why?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you want to *test* the performance or do you want to *measure* it - like measuring actual peak performance?

For testing, you usually have a performance spec, like saying, "the web site shall be able to handle 150 request per second". Then you create a test suite that sends 150 requests per second and you verifiy, that all requests are handled with the specified service quality.

For measuring - again you need one input: a specification, that tells you you maximum allowed time between an incoming request and an outgoing response. Then you could increase the RPS rate until the limits are reached.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Actually, my backend DB is experiencing some occasional deadlock, and I am trying to repro it with load/perf test. But during the test, many other problems occur such as socket forcibly closed and other errors totally unexpected. Is this because the RPS too high? But if I set the RPS low, I am afraid the deadlock is not going to be trigged. What a dilemma. Thanks.